# How Uninstall Theme Using command line in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, command-line, command, uninstall

How to uninstall or remove a theme using the command line In Magento 2.

Thank You...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command

> magento theme:uninstall

You can also define a theme path like below, you can add `--backup-code` to take backup

> magento theme:uninstall frontend/Magento/blank --backup-code

You can **Remove** themes from the **`theme` database table**.

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: Working for me  Thank You for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use this below command :

> magento theme:uninstall [--backup-code] [-c|--clear-static-content] {theme path} ... {theme path}

where

- {theme path} is the relative path to the theme, starting with the
  area name. For example, the path to the Blank theme supplied with
  Magento 2 is frontend/Magento/blank.
- --backup-code backs up the Magento 2 codebase as discussed in the paragraphs that follow.
- --clear-static-content cleans generated static view files, which is necessary to cause static view files to display properly.

For more referece : [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-theme-uninstall.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow below Magento manual for uninstalling a theme

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-uninstall.html

Comment: thank you for answer.